# Swift4.2 does not support stdatomic - what is a simple implementation of an atomic boolean?

Tags: swift4.2, stdatomic

I often use stdatomic in ObjectiveC files, but it doesn't yet (will it ever?) appear in Swift. I've found several open source frameworks that appear to offer the same functionality, but what I want is something small and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I [discovered the following code](https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/44685236/swift+3++atomic+boolean) that is working well for me:

```
struct AtomicBoolean {
    private var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    private var b: Bool
    var val: Bool  {
        get {
            semaphore.wait()
            let tmp = b
            semaphore.signal()
            return tmp
        }
        set {
            semaphore.wait()
            b = newValue
            semaphore.signal()
        }
    }
    init(_ initialState: Bool) {
        b = initialState
    }
}
```

It sure is small and efficient! DispatchSemaphores are also efficient, only going into kernel space if there is contention (reference Concurrency Programming Guide).

```
var foo = AtomicBoolean(false)
foo.var = true
if foo.var == true {
    print("See!")
}
```

Comment: Especially if all you need is atomic pure read / atomic pure write (not test-and-set or compare-exchange), taking a lock is much more expensive than needed in the no-contention case.  When compiled to asm, reading a C++ `std::atomic<bool>` is exactly as cheap as reading a non-atomic `bool` on x86.  (Or on weakly-ordered ISAs, `.load(std::memory_ordere_relaxed)` is exactly as cheap as a plain `bool`, but acquire or the default sequential consistency costs a load barrier instruction.)  And importantly, there's no contention between multiple readers.

Comment: Anyway, this works to give you a thread-safe `bool` (with read-modify-write operations as a TODO feature), but it's pretty far from equivalent to a lock-free atomic.

Comment: @PeterCordes would love stdatomic in Swift but not a whisper of it happening. Use it in ObjectiveC often.